# Algorithm or performance improvement for below code

Tags: python

I wrote the below program for one of the questions asked in the interview preparation websites. I would like to know if this code efficient or not or how can we improve if it is not efficient?

My problem

Write a function that takes an integer flight_length (in minutes) and a list of integers movie_lengths (in minutes) and returns a boolean indicating whether there are two numbers in movie_lengths whose sum equals flight_length.

When building your function:

Assume your users will watch exactly two movies
Don't make your users watch the same movie twice
Optimize for runtime over memory

```
def movie_length(fligh_length,movietimes):
  newmovietimes =[]
  for time in movietimes[0::]:
    if time not in newmovietimes:
      newmovietimes.append(time)
    else:
      print("movie times are equal")
  if fligh_length == sum(newmovietimes):
    return print("you can watch")
  else:
    return 

print("you can't watch")


movie_length(11,[8,2])
```

Comment: Review of working code should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The loop to reduce times to only unique times would certainly be more efficient with `newmovietimes = set(movietimes)` but this is a bug actually; if there are two 5-minute movies, you can watch them back to back in 10 minutes.

Your code doesn't solve the full problem if I understand it correctly; you should find two movies from a list of movie times, and if there are multiple combinations which satisfy the constraint, propose them all. Like for `(10, [4, 5, 6, 5])` you should find the combinations 6+4 and 5+5.

(In the end you only return a boolean to say whether you found an answer, so you can quit as soon as you find one; but your code should easily extend to find all permutations if necessary - that's what it takes to solve this completely anyway.)